# Copy target file before linking another (CMake)

Tags: cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that builds some c++ plugin and another CMakeLists.txt that builds application that should load this plugin. Before launching application I need to copy plugin file into some path, relative to the application binary (say `path_to_executable/Plugins`).

plugin's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...

add_library(plugin SHARED lib.cpp)

...
```

application's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...

target_sources(app PRIVATE main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(plugin_subfolder)
add_dependencies(app plugin)
???
```

How can I create rule that will insure plugin file is in correct place before compiling target `app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce you library directly to the place you need w/o any 2 step process of first creating it somewhere and then copying (which is also possible). To achieve this you can set the [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) property on your library:

```
set_target_properties(plugin PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY 
    "path_to_executable/Plugins")
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, it works! Is it possible to create separate target (e.g. `pluginCopy`) that will copy plugin to the location of `app`? I've tried to use `add_custom_command` + `add_custom_target` + generator expressions but it seems it creates cyclic dependencies.

Comment: @KamilZaripov, such things are usually done with the `INSTALL` target. You can read more on [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/install.html#installing-targets). So  you just list your targets and where to place them and by building the `INSTALL` target your files get distributed.